# Bulb Mode Problems EOS Cannon 70D

Tags: bulb-mode

I have my 70D On "B" for bulb mode and nothing shows up on the LED screen saying bulb, ive tried some settings and read the manual but it just says turn it to B mode and it should say Bulb on your LED screen. I've looked in the Q settings and can't find anything to do with bulb in my camera. Can someone help please?

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Photography on StackExchange.  I have (just occasionally) read reports of cameras where the camera is out of sync with the dial position.  Does the info screen accurately report other modes (e.g. Av, Tv, M, P, etc.)?

Comment: Hey Tim thank you :). I was fiddling with it last night and the when I turn the dial on the top to B on the info screen it skips right past B and goes to P. Also noticed when I turn the camera off the split secound I turn it off Bulb shows up in the bottom left hand corner. But when I turn it back on its still on P.

Comment: I have got in touch with canon technical support though email yesterday, just waiting on a reply. Had the camera about 4 years but only really wanted to start using the Bulb function for pictures of the night sky and stars. Bit of a pain because paid around £750-£800 for it and I'm not sure if I still have warranty.